ASP.NET Core 8 Redirect request if controller doesn't exist
I'm porting an app to .NET 8. I would like to port this existing app one section/controller/method at time. My hope is I can set something where if a request is made to a function that doesn't exist yet the caller can be redirected to the old app.
So when a get call is made to a controller that doesn't exist for example:
https://newhostname.example.com/data/historicData/

The caller would be redirected to the existing site:
https://oldhostname.example.com/data/historicData/

Ideally I would like to do this in the .NET 8 application vs setting an external reverse proxy.

Just to clarify, because you say the "new" code usess /NewAppUrl/... and the "old" website uses /OldAppUrl/... - do you mean they both run in the same IIS Website? (... and presumably, under separate Application Scopes?) because if not... you've got some explaining to do.

Same IIS instance two sites.

If you are using IIS why not using a URLRewrite so you can do one line of code and be done ?  Very easy to add it on and just have to get the proper statement in place to forward the old to the new in sort of a regex style format.

If they're separate IIS Websites then that means they have different Host: names and/or Port Numbers, so what you're asking is nontrivial...

So lame but worked...
I copied the existing site www.example.com to old.example.com.
I extracted all the controllers from the old site and added new controllers with the same name to the new site. Then copied each exposed method to the corresponding controller. Then in each method I did a Redirect to the old site. Then replaced www.expample.com with my new .NET Core site.
This wasn't quick. But does have some benefits. I can tell in code what calls are being serviced by the old site. Each one has a TODO so hopefully I can now bring in someone to help and they have a nice little TODO list.
I also added logging on each redirect so I can get a sense of how often some of these methods are getting called.
If the site was much bigger then it was I don't think this would be viable option.
